# Why is Azure Devops IterationId an Int for Workitem History?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the Azure DevOps API to query work items to understand the history of how the iteration has changed over time.

So I start with a typical work item query like so:

```
https://[ourserver]/[collection]/[project]/_apis/wit/workItems/[wi-id]/updates
```

And in the returned JSON I can see iteration changes. So far so good.

```
"System.IterationId": {
   "oldValue": 11068,
   "newValue": 11529
},
```

My problem is when I try to retrieve the full iteration record associated with those IDs. The REST API seems to use GUIDs for IDs, not ints. Here's an example:

```
https://[ourserver]/[collection]/[project]/[team]/apis/work/teamsettings/iterations

{
   "id": "3c117833-d770-47f1-a483-65461c440721",
   "name": "Sprint 3",
   "path": "aa\\bb\\cc\\Sprint 3",
   "attributes": {
      "startDate": "2020-02-05T00:00:00Z",
      "finishDate": "2020-02-18T00:00:00Z",
      "timeFrame": "past"
}
```

So where is the magic link between the `System.IterationId` in a workitem's history and GUID used for iteration ids in the REST API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the iterations id with the [Classification Nodes - Get Classification Nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/classification%20nodes/get%20classification%20nodes?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) Rest API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/classificationnodes?ids={ids}&api-version=5.1
```

You can use the URL parameter `$depth=2` to get also the children.

In the results, you will get `id` that is the `System.IterationId` value you get in the work item updates, and `identifier` that it's the GUID you get with the `teamsettings/iterations` api.

Comment: thx @Shayki, 99% there!  In my example I was able to find the new id 11529, but the previous id 11068 doesn't return anything.  Seems that AzDo might not remember deleted items.  I can't find any AsOf params to add the the URL, have you run across this problem?

Comment: @sisdog Hmm I didn't try it before, I don't think you have AsOf to this API :(